# Github : how to automaticaly set the base repository for PR merge

Tags: github, github-api

I have a base repository, and I do a first-level fork, then a 2nd level fork to create my repositories. example :

- base

  - type1 (type1 is a form of Base)

    - myrepo1 (myrepo1 is a fork from Type1)

the problem is that when I create a PR on myrepo1, the base repository for the merge is base

is there any way to set the "default" target branch for the "myrepo1" to the main branch for myrepo1 ? (via api or a settings in github)